# ReactNative App issue in the store

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, store

Hi i have this problem in my react native app : 
i use expo also 
    Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or 
    props of "Connect(App)". Either wrap the root component in a 
    , or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(App)".

My index.js file :

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import App from './App';
import configureStore from './src/store/configureStore';

const store = configureStore();

class Root extends React.Component {
render() { 
    return ( 
        <Provider store={store}>
            <App />
        </Provider>
    )
}
}

 AppRegistry.registerComponent('Root', () => Root);
```

I don't know where is the problem !!!

configureStore file :

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';

import placesReducer from './reducers/places';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    places: placesReducer
});

const configureStore = () => {
    return createStore(rootReducer);
};

export default configureStore;
```

App.js file :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import PlaceInput from "./src/components/PlaceInput/PlaceInput";
import PlaceList from "./src/components/PlaceList/PlaceList";
import PlaceDetail from "./src/components/PlaceDetail/PlaceDetail";
import {
  addPlace,
  deletePlace,
  selectPlace,
  deselectPlace
} from "./src/store/actions/index";

class App extends Component {
  placeAddedHandler = placeName => {
    this.props.onAddPlace(placeName);
  };

  placeDeletedHandler = () => {
    this.props.onDeletePlace();
  };

  modalClosedHandler = () => {
    this.props.onDeselectPlace();
  };

  placeSelectedHandler = key => {
    this.props.onSelectPlace(key);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <PlaceDetail
          selectedPlace={this.props.selectedPlace}
          onItemDeleted={this.placeDeletedHandler}
          onModalClosed={this.modalClosedHandler}
        />
        <PlaceInput onPlaceAdded={this.placeAddedHandler} />
        <PlaceList
          places={this.props.places}
          onItemSelected={this.placeSelectedHandler}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 26,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "flex-start"
  }
});

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    places: state.places.places,
    selectedPlace: state.places.selectedPlace
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onAddPlace: name => dispatch(addPlace(name)),
    onDeletePlace: () => dispatch(deletePlace()),
    onSelectPlace: key => dispatch(selectPlace(key)),
    onDeselectPlace: () => dispatch(deselectPlace())
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

package.json file :

```
{
  "name": "awesome-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-native-scripts": "1.14.0",
    "jest-expo": "~27.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^27.0.1",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-20.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

`

Comment: could you provide the package.json, App.js, and store/configureStore.js files content? Thanks

Comment: @AntonioRodriguez Done !

Comment: Have you solved this yet? According to the docs https://redux.js.org/recipes/writingtests#connected-components you may need to export the app component as well `export class App... `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [SGhaleb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7291516/sghaleb) pointed out in a comment your issue is that you missed exporting the Root component, but it must be exported as default.

`export default class Root extends React.Component {`

---

*If the error is not solved after you add the export default... consider this*

I found this issue trying to reproduce this question.
    I ran the latest *create-react-native-app*
    in this case inside the package.json the main(entry point) looks like this

`"main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",`

This cause me an issue, because **the index.js file was ignored** and the App.js in the root was used as entry point.

````
The workaround for this was 
    1 - move the App.js into the *src* folder 
    2 - update the import reference in the *index.js* file.
        ```import App from './src/App';```
    3 - rename *index.js* to *App.js*
````

I leave a capture to be more clear. 
Good luck!

[image: capture]